# Nested for loop not returning to outer loop

Tags: java, json, for-loop

I am having an issue with a nested for-loop that I have written.  Essentially I have a JSON file that I am trying to parse into individual variables so that I can then add those variables to a database for querying.

This is the outer and inner loop:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= fixtures.length; x++) {                
    String testFixture = fixtures[x];
    testFixture = testFixture.replace("\"", "");
    testFixture = testFixture.replace("[", "");
    testFixture = testFixture.replace("{", "");
    testFixture = testFixture.replace("}", "");
    String[] singleFixture = testFixture.split(",");

    for (int i = 0; i <= singleFixture.length; i++) {
        //System.out.println(singleFixture[i]);
        String test = singleFixture[i];
        String[] fix1 = test.split(":");
        singleFixtureComplete.add(fix1[0]);
        singleFixtureComplete.add(fix1[1]);
    }
    singleFixtureComplete.add(Arrays.toString(singleFixture));
}
```

The output of this is a json array at fixtures[0] and that's it...

fixtures.length = 381.  So I would expect that when the inner loop finishes, it will return to the top of the outer loop and x would be incremented by +1.

What's happening is the inner loops finishes and that's it.  x does not iterate to fixtures.length i.e. 381 times.

Each index in fixtures is a JSON array with 34 key pairs.  So singleFixture.length = 34.  That works, i iterates 34 times.  Then the loop ends and the outer loop is ignored.

Does anyone have any ideas what I've done wrong here?

Comment: You will be getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Use `i < singleFixture.length` instead of `i <= singleFixture.length`. Or, easier, `for (String[] test : singleFixture) {`, since you never actually use `i` otherwise.

Comment: Side note: you might want to read about the Single Level of Abstraction principle. You won't believe how much easier code becomes to read if you avoid putting so much code into one place.

Comment: Use your debugger for step-by-step execution and you will be able to see for yourself quite literally.

Comment: Thanks PM 77-1 I did that already which is why I am on here...

Comment: Andy Turner, I didn't get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException... sorry

Comment: Just as side note. You may use a `JSON library` for Java, higher abstraction level, makes it much easier to process such complex data. Here's a link that compares some of them: http://blog.takipi.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/

Comment: Thanks Zabuza, will look at it now.  But for now, the for loop issue I am having still stands, if anyone can help me with that it would be great.

Comment: Thanks Jagermeister, as you can tell I am at beginner level java...

Comment: Are you sure that your program didn't died because of `index out of bound` exception? It should thou. Try putting a print statement outside of the main `for-loop` and you should see it not getting executed.

Comment: @SamuelToh  Yes, 100% sure that it didn't crash.  When I used the debugger and stepped into the for loops it works on the fixtures[0] index and parses the data in that array index.  My expectation is that it would go back up and do that for array index [1], then [2], then... until fixtures.length was satisfied.

Comment: @SamuelToh I did have a print statement... System.out.println(singleFixtureComplete.toString());  It was in the complete code that I posted and you edited.

Comment: You are probably catching the exception somewhere silently.

Comment: This is what I thought too. Impossible to not run the 2nd iteration. Can you please show the entire method within that piece of code?

Comment: Can you give us some sample json data you are parsing?

Comment: @SamuelToh I added the complete program... sorry if it is a bit messy, as I said I am a beginner.

Comment: @angryip sure, but it is 18000 line json file :/

Comment: You are catching the exception.

Comment: @StevenBranigan geez, do you not have a smaller sample?

Comment: @SamuelToh looking at his original post, he is stating that he is not getting an exception. if he was, the sout statement would tell him. The issue seems to be in the loop, which can be solved by examining the test data

Comment: @angryip sorry mate, I copied and pasted a small section of it.. haha, thanks for taking a look too btw, appreciate it

Comment: @SamuelToh Thanks Samuel, you're 100% right, it is throwing an error.  Any idea why though?

Comment: @Zabuza Thanks for the json.simple info.  Very useful.  Managed to get the same results as before with half the code.  Appreciate that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your `loop` did not went to its next iteration was because the `try-catch` clause is catching your exception. See the `try-catch` located outside of the main `for-loop` block.

```
 //!!! The try is catching the exception for you. Remove it to see the real problem.
 try {
        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("http://api.fantasydata.net/soccer/v2/json/Schedule/73");
        ...
        for (int x = 0; x <= fixtures.length; x++) {
            // Exception somewhere
        }
    }
  catch(Exception e) {

  }
```

**Q:**
So what do you have to do to make the problem obvious?

**A:**
Try;

1. Commenting out the `try-catch` clause
2. adding  `throws Exception` to the `main` method;
   `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception`

This should leave you with some stack trace for further investigation.

Also, as mentioned by others the loop logic you got there is wrong. It should be `<` less than **not** `<=`, the latter will definitely trigger an `index out of bound` exception.

**Theory:**

Just an observation - I think the nested loop is triggering the index of out bound exception and hence the issue? As a first step I would fix both loop logic first.

Well if you are still having trouble and you would like us to have a look at the stack trace, please kindly post another question and we can take this further.

Glad to help.

Comment: Thanks Samuel, I will follow your suggestion and hopefully fix the issue myself.  Thanks everyone for your help and suggestions.

Comment: No worries. It is likely that the nested `for-loop` triggered an `index-out-of-bound` exception which causes the entire loop to end. So I would recommend to fix the loop conditions first, `<` instead. Not `<=`

Comment: @angryip  Thank you both... I fixed it.  The error was caused by a rouge character in the json file.  It is working now.  I appreciate all your help guys.  I owe you both a beer!

Comment: @StevenBranigan great! I'll send you me address for that beer.